# Problem with parsing info from a json api

Tags: python, json

I am parsing some data from a trivia api for a bot I'm working on, I'm pulling it from https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1&type= and when I parse it through this code

```
response = requests.get('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1&type=')
data = response.text
parsed = json.loads(data)
question = parsed["results"]["question"]
await ctx.send(question)
```

I get this error:

```
list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I was getting pure json before I parsed it, but now it just keeps giving me this error. It might have to do with the way I'm parsing it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due to parsed['results'] being a list not a dictionary. so you would need to specify what item in the result list you want (0 for the first item, 1 for the second, etc).
Also, the request response object has a built-in .json() method so no need to use json.loads

```
response = requests.get('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1&type=')
parsed = response.json()
question = parsed["results"][0]["question"]
await ctx.send(question)
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you don't need get text and then convert to json:

```
data = response.text
parsed = json.loads(data)
```

requests has feature convert response to json by:

```
response.json()
```

error appears on the step of getting ["question"] from parsed["results"],
because parsed["results"] is list type and you should get it by number like 0

```
question = parsed["results"][0]
```

and then you can get question:

```
question = parsed["results"][0]['question']
await ctx.send(question)
```